# How to store a new record in gnome keyring via secret-tool in an ansible task or how to pipe stdin in an ansible shell task?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to store a new password record in gnome keyring programmatically in an ansible task. As there is no dedicated ansible module for this task, I tried the `shell` module - but I struggle to pass the password for my new record.

The (bash) task to convert in an ansible task is:

```sh
$ echo "mysecret" | secret-tool store \
    --label='secret_label' 'secret_key 'secret_value'
```

The man page for secret-tool states that

> A password to store can also be piped in via stdin. The password will
>   be the contents of stdin until EOF. If you provide a newline via stdin
>   it will be stored as part of the password.

But I did not manage to pipe the password in via stdin in my ansible task:

```
- name: Ensure gnome keyring entry for secret_label exists
  shell: secret-tool store --label='{{ secret_label }}' '{{ secret_key }}' '{{ secret_value }}'
  args:
    stdin: "{{ mysecret }}"
    stdin_add_newline: false
```

This task do not yield any errors but did not create a new password record in gnome keyring.

How could I pipe `mysecret` as stdin to my ansible shell command?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your playbook.  When you use the `|` literal block operator, the content of the block is used *verbatim* -- including newlines.  This means that when you write:

```
  shell: |
    secret-tool store 
    --label='{{ secret_label }}' 
    '{{ secret_key }}' '{{ secret_value }}'
```

You're trying to run the follow three separatae commands:

1. `secret-tool store`
2. `--label='{{ secret_label }}'`
3. `'{{ secret_key }}' '{{ secret_value }}'

This will fail because none of those are valid commands. If I run that myself I get as output:

```
TASK [shell] **************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "secret-tool store\n--label='secret_label'\n'secret_key' 'secret_Value'\n", "delta": "0:00:00.005253", "end": "2019-11-17 19:20:41.147034", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-11-17 19:20:41.141781", "stderr": "secret-tool: must specify a label for the new item\nusage: secret-tool store --label='label' attribute value ...\n       secret-tool lookup attribute value ...\n       secret-tool clear attribute value ...\n       secret-tool search [--all] [--unlock] attribute value ...\n/bin/sh: line 1: --label=secret_label: command not found\n/bin/sh: line 2: secret_key: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["secret-tool: must specify a label for the new item", "usage: secret-tool store --label='label' attribute value ...", "       secret-tool lookup attribute value ...", "       secret-tool clear attribute value ...", "       secret-tool search [--all] [--unlock] attribute value ...", "/bin/sh: line 1: --label=secret_label: command not found", "/bin/sh: line 2: secret_key: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

There are a couple of different ways to fix this.  One option is to write it the same way you would write any other multi-line command and use backslashes to extend your command across multiple lines:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    secret_label: secret_label
    secret_key: secret_key
    secret_value: secret_value
    mysecret: mysecret

  tasks:
    - shell: |
        secret-tool store \
        --label='{{ secret_label }}' \
        '{{ secret_key }}' '{{ secret_value }}'
      args:
        stdin: "{{ mysecret }}"
        stdin_add_newline: false
```

You could also use the YAML folding block operator, `>`, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    secret_label: secret_label
    secret_key: secret_key
    secret_value: secret_value
    mysecret: mysecret

  tasks:
    - shell: >
        secret-tool store
        --label='{{ secret_label }}'
        '{{ secret_key }}' '{{ secret_value }}'
      args:
        stdin: "{{ mysecret }}"
        stdin_add_newline: false
```

The end result in this case is the same.  In both cases, after running the above playbook, I see:

```
$ secret-tool lookup secret_key secret_value
mysecret
```

Comment: Dear @larsks , thanks for your comment - my weird multiline shell block is not my "production code", I just wanted to make SO's line length happy.  In fact, it is just a oneliner in my code. I will revert that edit.

Comment: I think the problem with not getting a password entry in my keyring is because some env vars are missing or not set correct, namely ``DISPLAY`` and ``DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS``.  When setting these via ``environment`` for my shell task, it works.